# photo upload script - rotate, change places, crop, remove thumbinails?

Tags: php, jquery, upload, photo

maybe some one knows a photo upload script where people can see theirs uploaded photos thumbinails and can make actions with them? I mean, they can remove photos, change sequence of them and rotate them? Also there has to be a thumbinail on fixed size, like in this script:

http://www.saaraan.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-with-progressbar-with-jquery-and-php

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: well, taht's not what i needed... i would like to get a full script with jquery functions and etc.

Comment: We dont provide full script here. If you are facing problem ask a question we'll be happy to answer.